# Craft 2.6 Asset Upload 500 Error (EC2 and Amazon S3)

Tags: assets, upload, aws

Our site is hosted on AWS with assets uploading to an S3. Everything has worked great until the last update. Locally, I can upload assets without issue, but on the stage we're receiving an error `/index.php?p=admin/actions/assets/uploadFile 500 (Internal Server Error)` preventing us from uploading. The files upload to the directory, but the upload bar hangs.

Within the assets directory when pressing "refresh" on the bucket name, we receive the error `/index.php?p=admin/actions/assetSources/getS3Buckets 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Craft Version: `Craft CMS 2.6.2950`

This is the data from the logs.

---

```
2016/11/14 12:05:47 [error] [exception.Error] Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/lib/S3.php:2221
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/lib/S3.php(420): S3Request->getResponse()
#1 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/assetsourcetypes/S3AssetSourceType.php(438): S3::getBucket('website-craft', 'banners/IR_shar...')
#2 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/assetsourcetypes/BaseAssetSourceType.php(237): Craft\S3AssetSourceType->getNameReplacementInFolder(Object(Craft\AssetFolderModel), 'IR_shareholder_...')
#3 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/assetsourcetypes/BaseAssetSourceType.php(172): Craft\BaseAssetSourceType->insertFileByPath('/var/www/stage....', Object(Craft\AssetFolderModel), 'IR_shareholder_...')
#4 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/services/AssetsService.php(709): Craft\BaseAssetSourceType->uploadFile(Object(Craft\AssetFolderModel))
#5 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/controllers/AssetsController.php(52): Craft\AssetsService->uploadFile('1', NULL, 0, NULL)
#6 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\AssetsController->actionUploadFile()
#7 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#8 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#9 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#10 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('uploadFile')
#11 /var/www/stage.mediatek.com/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(818): CWebApplication->runController('assets/uploadFi...')
#12 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(288): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
#13 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#14 /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#15 /var/www/stage.website.com/public/index.php(19): require_once('/var/www/stage....')
#16 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/index.php?p=admin/actions/assets/uploadFile
HTTP_REFERER=http://stage.website.com/admin/assets
---
```

--

```
2016-11-14 20:25:28

Level   error
Category    exception.Error
Message Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in /var/www/stage.website.com/craft/app/lib/S3.php:2221
```

We haven't made any system changes, so I'm unsure what the next step is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and say this looks like a bug and vote to close. But would you mind shooting an email to support@craftcms.com with a link to this thread as well as the file you're trying to upload?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently PHP hadn't installed the XML Parser appropriately. The amazing Craft team provided this link. Which solved my issue.

`sudo apt-get install php-xml`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35604148/520520